# Include files in custom Eclipse with Oomph

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I am creating a custom Eclipse distro with Oomph and I would like to add additional directories/files into my installation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a file somewhere you can use the task type "Ressource Creation".

[image: Add a Ressource Creation Task in Oomph]

In the properties view for the new created new you will be able to set:

- **Target URL**: the location of the file
- **Content**: the file content

In the location you can use other variables for example `${workspace.location|uri}/.metadata/info.txt` will create a new file `info.txt` in the `.metadata` folder in the current workspace folder.

In the outline view (when your setup file is opened), you can see all available variables ("Resolved Variables" means the values will be computed, "Unresolved Variables" means oomph will prompt some input fields to set the values).

[image: Oomph outline view]

---

I guess the "Resource Copy" task works in a similar way.